# ROS Answers SE migration: uninstallation

Tags: ros, cturtle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does "sudo apt-get remove ros-cturtle-ros" also removes other packages in my home folder? If not, could I just manually delete them or is there a recommended method?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9226/uninstallation/) by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 475 on 2011-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sudo apt-get remove ros-cturtle-ros will remove all cturtle packages in /opt/ros but not do anything in your home directory.

To remove things from your home directory `rm -rf ~/ROS` or whatever path you want to remove will work.  Or, if you wish, you can delete the directories from a file browser GUI.

Note: There's no undo for rm so make sure you get the path right.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1